# generating time values

Tags: mysql

I have to generate time values (minutes) between 5 and 30.The code should work and generate 5-30 minutes but instead of that I get 5-30 seconds:

> update table1
>        set column1 = 5+FLOOR(RAND()*26);
>
> column1 is a TIME column

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the format of column1 ? Why don't you simply multiply by 60 ?

Comment: the format of column 1 is time

Comment: Did you read the doc ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html

Comment: as I said in the first place, with my code I get from 5 to 30 seconds, multiplying it by 60 it gives error cause it generates seconds I guess ( over 500 )

Comment: of course I've read the doc and i tried to solve it in many ways including with curtime add date etc and didn't work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just storing a number of seconds or minutes then you are not storing a 'time' so column1 should not be a time type...

If you want whole minutes (in seconds)

```
update table1 set column1 = (5+FLOOR(RAND()*26)) * 60;
```

If you want partial minutes (in seconds)

```
update table1 set column1 = (5*60)+FLOOR(RAND()*26*60);
```

If you just want a whole number of minutes (5 to 30) then your original query should be fine once you change the column type to int

Comment: not working: Error Code: 1292. Incorrect time value: '480' for column 'Durata' at row 4

Comment: `Durata` should be an integer or float type, not a time type

Comment: same thing I get large numbers, I guess are seconds or something like that. Instead of generating like I said minutes between 5 and 30 I get 1082 etc

Comment: So you're saying i should maybe set the column to a tinyint ? Gonna try and see what happens

Comment: Yeah it works this way even though I kind of wanted to keep the TIME column since I generated an interval between 5 and 30 seconds instead of minutes. Really thought i could make that work anyway thanks for the heads up with changing the type of the column